# Trying to edit my javascript button using css

Tags: javascript, css

```css
.button {
   border-top: 1px solid #262626;
   background: #f02805;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#f02805));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   padding: 5.5px 11px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: Georgia, Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.button:hover {
   border-top-color: #9c1c13;
   background: #9c1c13;
   color: #ffffff;
   }
.button:active {
   border-top-color: #e82b12;
   background: #e82b12;
   }
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">The Red Hot Chili Peppers</button>
```

I wanted the buttons to not be that boring classic windows button look. i got the css the way I wanted it but it isn't showing in the button.
What am I doing wrong that is causing the button to now have the defined style??
What am I missing to make it work?

Comment: Your button is using an id, but your css is using a class. `#idgoeshere` for id, `.classgoeshere` for class, when writing css.  However even if you were using the correct syntax, your code is still referenced wrong.

Comment: Please remove the dot before the style name. Dot referes to the class and not the HTML element. Or, you can simply change your button to `<button id="myBtn" class="button">Text</button>`

Comment: ahh, thank you. I'm new to coding so the help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`button` is not a class, it's an html object. Either reference an item in css by a class name using `.<<classname>>` or by id `#<<id here>>` or, reference all elements by using the element in this case `button` without `.` or `#`:

Example:

```css
button {
   border-top: 1px solid #262626;
   background: #f02805;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#f02805));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   padding: 5.5px 11px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: Georgia, Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
button:hover {
   border-top-color: #9c1c13;
   background: #9c1c13;
   color: #ffffff;
   }
button:active {
   border-top-color: #e82b12;
   background: #e82b12;
   }
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">The Red Hot Chili Peppers</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, noob error, which i am new to this so its to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

`.button` is class selector. There is no reference of `button` class in your html. I guess you are looking for `button` which is a tag selector in css.

So replace `.button` with `button` in css or add class button to html

```
<button id="myBtn" class ="button">The Red Hot Chili Peppers</button>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/jvk5fmr9/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove "#myBtn" from button HTML tag and add class instead which you are in css for styling which is ".button". So your button tag looks like:

```css
.button {
   border-top: 1px solid #262626;
   background: #f02805;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#f02805));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   padding: 5.5px 11px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: Georgia, Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.button:hover {
   border-top-color: #9c1c13;
   background: #9c1c13;
   color: #ffffff;
   }
.button:active {
   border-top-color: #e82b12;
   background: #e82b12;
   }
```

```html
<button class="button">The Red Hot Chili Peppers</button>
```

Comment: Yeah there is nothing wrong but he was using "id" in button attribute while using class for its styling.

Answer (score 0):

```css
button {
   border-top: 1px solid #262626;
   background: #f02805;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#f02805));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   padding: 5.5px 11px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: Georgia, Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
button:hover {
   border-top-color: #9c1c13;
   background: #9c1c13;
   color: #ffffff;
   }
button:active {
   border-top-color: #e82b12;
   background: #e82b12;
   }
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">The Red Hot Chili Peppers</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button uses an id, your css references a class .button, should be #myBtn or button

```css
#myBtn {
   border-top: 1px solid #262626;
   background: #f02805;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#f02805));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   padding: 5.5px 11px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: Georgia, Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
#myBtn:hover {
   border-top-color: #9c1c13;
   background: #9c1c13;
   color: #ffffff;
   }
#myBtn:active {
   border-top-color: #e82b12;
   background: #e82b12;
   }
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">The Red Hot Chili Peppers</button>
```

```css
button {
   border-top: 1px solid #262626;
   background: #f02805;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#000000), to(#f02805));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000, #f02805);
   padding: 5.5px 11px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: Georgia, Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
button:hover {
   border-top-color: #9c1c13;
   background: #9c1c13;
   color: #ffffff;
   }
button:active {
   border-top-color: #e82b12;
   background: #e82b12;
   }
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">The Red Hot Chili Peppers</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

add your button class name in HTMl

```
<button class ="button" id="myBtn">The Red Hot Chili Peppers</button>
```